# How to deal with a very slow PreparedStatement

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I looked around a bit and couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

I’m writing code to query a PowerHub database which occasionally goes very slowly. When I ran the query in an external client, it took >1000 seconds. I've tried writing a timeout, but it never throws the exception:

```
wbPstmt.setQueryTimeout(30);
try{
    wbRs = wbPstmt.executeQuery();
    if(wbRs.next()) 
        ; // do some stuff
} catch(SQLException e){
    // some stuff
}
```

It seems to hang on the wbRs.next() statement. Is there another way to get it to timeout when dealing with a very slow database? How do I keep the program from freezing for several minutes?

Comment: Optimising the query might yield results. Could you post that?

Comment: @MikeW, it's a PowerHub query, and since they use views that draw data from multiple sources on multiple computers - or so I understand - they can be quite slow. However, on most days, the query runs fast enough. Is there any way to abort when it's lagging?

Comment: It depends what the driver supports, not all jdbc drivers support all functions. You may need to spin the result set read into another thread and have the main thread time out if it takes too long.